# SQL Query strange error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When I execute this query the following error is displayed.

> [Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.]

I am wondering that the error is in the comparison part that is `fb_userevents.userid = '100002917025417'` when this long string within the single quot is replaced by 1 or 0 it works. Instead of quote (') around it why it tries to convert into float??

I am using SQL Server 2005

```
select
    fb_event.eventname
from
    fb_event
inner join
    fb_userevents on fb_userevents.eventid = fb_event.eventid  
where 
    fb_userevents.userid = '100002917025417' 
    and DATEDIFF(hh,fb_event.startdate,getdate()) < 0 
    and  acos(sin(0) * sin(convert(float,altitude)) + 
         cos(0) * cos(convert(float,altitude)) *
         cos(convert(float,longitude) - 101)) * 6371 <= 1000
```

The altitutes and longitutes of that user: 
[image]

Comment: oh of course. I forgot id fields should be strings. And there's me using integers....

Comment: The error will be coming from an invalid value in `altitude` or `longitude`

Comment: what happens if you try '25417' for the value?  As Martin is pointing out that's a really big number that may be getting treated differently.  Martin may be able to provide that as the answer if so.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - I deleted that part of my comment because the OP says `userid` is `varchar` and they are passing a string to it so there should be no numeric casting going on there at all in that bit. Clearly the values being returned when the `where` clause is changed are just different and not valid numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the problem isn't with this line?

```
cos(convert(float,altitude))
```

What data type is altitude? And does every value in that column only contain numeric characters?

Comment: @XXXcoder - That's what you think! Of course you can't guarantee this as you are using the wrong datatype. Try `select convert(float,altitude),convert(float,longitude) from your_table`

Comment: @XXXcoder - I'm strongly inclined to agree with Martin that, if `altitude` or `longitude` are VARCHAR fields, you have at least one string value that can not be converted to a FLOAT value.

Comment: @Dems, I have added the screen shot of the filtered alt and long of that user. Can you see any unconvertable thing thre?

Comment: @XXXcoder - It doesn't have to belong to that user. The `CONVERT` can get pushed to before the `WHERE` so potentially any invalid value in those columns can mess you up.

Comment: @XXXcoder - Factors such as indexes can cause (as Martin states) the Trigonometric condition to be evaluated before the user_id condition.  To check this, you could look at the execution plan of the query.  Additionally, I would recommend sanity checking all records in your table to see if the values can be converted to FLOAT or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do an explicit cast or convert on that field.